# How to get result of the formula on import xlsx with maatwebsite using Laravel? I get formula and not value of the formula

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Please advise!
During import of xlsx file I get formula and not result of the Formula.

Changed config file excel.php to set 'calculate'=> true, on imports and still doesn't work.

MyModel

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\ImpData;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;

class ImpDataImport implements ToModel
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new ImpData([
            'f1' => $row[1],
            'f2' => $row[2],
            'f3' => $row[3],
            'f4' => $row[4],
            'f5' => $row[5],
            'f6' => $row[6],
            'f7' => $row[7],
            'f8' => $row[8],
            'f9' => $row[9],
            'f10' => $row[10],
            'f11' => $row[11],
            'f12' => $row[12],
            'f13' => $row[13],
            'f14' => $row[14],
            'f15' => $row[15],
            'f16' => $row[16],
            'f17' => $row[17],
            'f18' => $row[18]
        ]);
    }
}
```

In My Controller

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new ImpDataImport(), $file);
```

Source file:

```
A1 = '1'
A2 = '2'
A3 = '=A1+B1'
```

After import I get:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      0 => 1.0
      1 => 2.0
      2 => "=A1+B1"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: hey, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your class as

```
class ImpDataImport implements ToModel, WithCalculatedFormulas
```

for it to work. Just added this for any future viewers of this question.